# Roo install issue class loading

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to run Roo Spring 1.2.5 on ubuntu 14.04..
And have an error.

```
    laptop:~$ roo
    ERROR: Bundle com.github.antlrjavaparser.antlr-java-parser [3] Error starting file:~/STS_Eclipse/ROO/bundle/antlr-java-parser-1.0.14.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.github.antlrjavaparser.antlr-java-parser [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] package; (package=org.antlr.v4.runtime) [caused by: Unable to resolve 74.0: missing requirement [74.0] package; (package=javax.imageio)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Roo doesn't support Java 8 yet. Try with JDK 7.

Comment: Note Spring Roo 1.3.1 supports Java 8.